# list.count() method returning count + 1 for the first value in iterable

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count

I was working on one problem while I encountered this problem. Let me explain through a simple example:

```
a = ['hello', 'world']
print(a.count('hello')) #prints 1 correctly
```

But...

```
a = "hello world"
for i in a.split():
    print(a.count(i))

#prints
#2 -> for 'hello' which is wrong, one more than actual value
#1 -> counts of elements from 2nd onwards are correct
```

If I `split` it before, it works perfectly:

```
a = 'hello world'
a = a.split()
for i in a:
    print(a.count(i))

#correctly prints
1
1
```

So I think the issue only happens when I use the `split` method directly in the for loop, but I'm not sure why.

**Edit:**

I rechecked it, and its printing wrong values for long statements, specifically for this one. Please check using this statement below:

"how many times does each word show up in this sentence word times each each word"

**Edit 2:**

Even though I was splitting the string in for loop directly, it did't change the original string and I was using count method on original string inside the for loop, which caused the error and the 'how' to show up two times.

Thanks to the user Bobby, for correctly pointing out.

Comment: First attempt works the same way as second attempt does. Please show your full code. Could not reproduce.

Comment: Yeah, please check the edits. Its not working for longer strings

Comment: "how" shows up twice in that new string you added. It's part of "show".

Comment: Yeah got it now. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `a` has never been updated. Even in the for loop, you split `a` but that didn't update `a`. You can verify this directly:

```
a = "hello world"
for i in a.split():
    print(a)
    print(a.count(i))
```

If you want the split string you need to save that to a variable like you did in the first example. You can do this within the for loop if you want:

```
a = "hello world"
for i in b:=a.split():
    print(b.count(i))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This clears it all. All the way I was thinking it must be some really trivial logic and here it is. Thanks again!

Comment: `for i in b:=a.split():` is gross

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You don't like walrus operators?

Comment: Not there, I don't. It's much more clear to create the variable on a previous line, with zero benefits doing it inside the for clause... This is exactly the sort of thing people that were against assignment expressions were talking about.

Comment: It is, ultimately though, a matter of opinion

Answer (score 3):

It's works fine on my machine with Python 3.10.0.
I get 1s in every example.
Please provide more info like Python version, maybe we'll get the reason why it works like that on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

`count` counts how many times the argument is found in a list.  So for your first example:

```
a = ['hello', 'world']
print(a.count('hello'))
```

Hello is only in the list once.

```
a = ['hello', 'hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world']
print(a.count('hello')
```

Would return 3.

Answer (score 0):

The function `count` when used on a string iterates the entire string for any match. It doesn't care about "words".

```
"abc".count("ab") # 1
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
str.count(sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

In your first example you use `count` on the string.

When used on lists however, it does not do partial matchign between the items:

```
["a", "b", "c"].count("ab") # 0
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list.count(x)
```

> Return the number of times x appears in the list.

This is what you do in your second example. You use `count` on a list. This happens **because `str.split` returns a list**.

So these are **two different count methods** you're using. One for strings (first example - `a` is a string) and one for lists (second example - `a` is a list returned from `str.split`).

Comment: Yes correct. My confusion was that I didnt even know I was using count() on the original string and not on the splitted list.

Comment: @Aniruddha789 I wrote some more information about these being different methods (`str.count` and `list.count`) and why. Good Luck.